# Ansible colorize a result in file

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have the following script in Ansible:

```
--- #Available RAM 
- hosts: all
  sudo: yes
  user: ansible
  connection: ssh
  vars:
    RAM: ansible_memory_mb.real.total
  tasks: 
  - fail: msg="Not enough RAM"
    when: ansible_memory_mb.real.total < 100
    ignore_errors: yes 
    tags: available_ram
  - name: Basic checks
    template: src=../templates/template.conf.j2 dest=/home/ansible/monit{{ansible_hostname}}.log owner=ansible mode=750
```

And the following Jinja2 conf file which will create the .log file:

```
{{ansible_hostname}} RAM available: {{ansible_memory_mb.real.total}}mb
```

Is any way to colorize the result from the log file just if will not be enough RAM available?

Best regards,
Dan

Comment: Please provide an example of **colorized log file** so we can advice you something...

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov: Here is the output of the template for one server: 
server1 172.31.24.178 Disk usage: 14617.079808mb RAM available: 1837mb Uptime:9018s CPULoad:0.00. If RAM is less than 100, should be marked with red. If is bigger than 100, then should be marked with green.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you ask. But do you know any text log file that has colours inside? If yes, please provide such example.

Comment: For example, if you have the CCZE installed, you can see the output colorized. I think that any kind of log file can be seen colorized afterwards, if there are some variable marked with some specific colors.